# Why does python numpy not have cotangens related functions e.g. arccot?

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, numerical-stability

I try to calculate the `arctan(a/b)` by calculating `arccot(b/a)` for small `b` and larger `a` to increase numerical stability of my calculations but numpy seems not to provide an arccot function?

Edit:
Ok @hpaulj pointed out there is an arctan2 / tan2 function. I looked it up and it basically removes the numerical stability problems by not dividing at all but taking the numerator and denominator as separate inputs.

Comment: Maybe because `c` doesn't have it either?  Or because it's easy to derive from the `tan` or `tan2` functions?